# How would you prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Imagine you have $\{a_n\}$ which follows the next formula:
$$
a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}
$$
First we will prove if the succession converges;
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)n!}{(n + 1)(n+1)^n} = \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n} \\
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}} = \frac{n^n}{(n + 1)^n} = \left ( \frac{n}{n + 1} \right)^n < 1 \\ \Rightarrow a_{n+1} < a_n
$$
Thus converges and is a decreasing succession and is bottom bounded (No?).

But how would you calculate the value that the succession converges to? The first idea that came to my mind was to bound the succession:
$$0 < a_n = \frac{1 \times 2 \times3 \times \ldots \times n}{n \times n \times n \times\ldots\times n} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$

Each factor of denumerator is less or equal to $n$, hence if we group each factor with an $n$ from the denominator, we will have a product of values smaller or equal to $1$.
Is this correct? I'm making any assumptions that I must prove?

Therefore:
$$
 a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n} \land  b_n = \frac{1}{n} \\
0 < a_n \leq b_n \\
a_n \text { converges and is botton bounded, then: } \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = l
$$
Hence we proved that:
$$
a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} = 0
$$
I would like to know if this line of reasoning is correct. Is there any other way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me

Comment: It seems like it should be easier to use the squeeze theorem: $0 \le a_n \le \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Why $0$? How you arrive to that conclusion? I mean, nothing garantees you that the succession is bounded by $0$, no? (unless you derive it)

Comment: I don't know how to properly put it, but each $a_n$ is basically a product (including division) of multiple factors which are all positive. So the overall term must be positive, hence $a_n > 0$. Just from the definition.

Comment: Ahhhh, makes sense to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the ratio  test?

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n + 1)!}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}\frac{n^{n}}{n!}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n}}{(n + 1)^{n}}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n + 1}\right)^{n}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\\\\
& = e^{-1} < 1.
\end{align*}
Since the proposed limit converges to $0 < e^{-1} < 1$, we conclude the following series converges:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} < +\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = 0.
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You have proved a stronger claim than the one in the question, that's probably why. There's a much easier way to prove the limit itself. But I see no problem with your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since $n\to +\infty$ we can appeal to [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \dfrac{n^n}{e^n}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \dfrac{n!}{n^n} \sim \lim_{n\to +\infty} \sqrt{n} e^{-n} = 0$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. However, the OP doesn't ask for another proof, but to check if the proof he provided is correct. By the way, it is correct and avoids using the over-killing Stirling approximation for the given sequence.

Comment: I also didn't downvote but this is definitely a nuclear flyswatter.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net But he wrote "Is there any other way to do this more efficiently?" I though we wanted another sort of proof (?)

Comment: I didn't downvoted... There is nothing bad with your answer.